# Change background colour based on current background colour

Tags: excel, vba

just playing around with vba, wanted to see if I could make the screen blink, but having trouble.

I'm getting an object error at the moment.

```
Sub disco()

Dim col As Range
Cells.Select
Set col = Selection.Interior.ColorIndex

If col = 0 Then
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
ElseIf col = 1 Then
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If

Range("a1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub disco()
    Dim col As Variant
    Cells.Select
    col = Selection.Interior.ColorIndex
    If col = -4142 Then
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ElseIf col = 1 Then
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
    End If
    Range("a1").Select
End Sub
```

***NOTES:***

we use *col* as a **Variant**
we do not use 0